# Bezier Curve - Split one large end into multiple wires

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Would that even be possible?

I have one large, Bezier curve wire, made using a Bezier Circle.
I need to extrude that end into several, smaller wires.

How should I proceed? Is that even possible? Or do I have to create separate curves/circles?
I need it to be as seamless as possible too.

[image]

Comment: do you need to do it with bezier or can it be done with mesh? also, could you please make a drawing of what you want? not sure you can do it with curves

Comment: Hi Moonbots, please see my edited posts. I need something like that. The large end of the bezier curve to split into multiple, smaller wires. I just need the end result to be like that, doesn't matter what method is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have two segments attached to a point in a curve, but you can have multiple disconnected segments in the same curve object.

[image: curve with multiple segments]

While in edit mode, many of the steps you use in mesh editing work in a similar way.

- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add a new curve that is part of the existing object
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the current selection
- <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude a segment that is connected to the selected point/s
- <kbd>L</kbd> to select points linked to the point under the cursor
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select points linked to selected points
- <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a segment between two selected points

Each point has a radius property so you can give the shielding a larger bevel than the inner wires. You use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to adjust the radius of a point, this can also be edited in the properties sidebar.

[image: adjusting a points radius]

The disconnected pieces can be positioned close together so that the smaller wires appear to continue on inside the larger wire. Different materials can be assigned to different curve segments the same as assigning materials to selected faces in a mesh.

[image: assign materials]

Then after setting the bevel, you get one object that appears to be multiple wires.

[image: wire with multiple segments and materials]