# What am I doing wrong with shading and modeling?

Tags: shaders

How would you create the vines of the wood, because I'm not sure how to approach that before getting to sculpting, and what is the problem with the shading?

I still don't understand how to avoid shading problems like that.

[image: Vine]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122563/110840 - i would lean towards curves for decorative vines or wire

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because you have a large ngon that Blender tries to shade smooth with the adjacent faces. Ngons, under the hood and like any other faces, are made of tris, but contrary to quads the tris organization can be messy, therefore the bad shading. You need to convert your ngon to a series of quads, see the difference:

[image]

On your topology it should give something like that:

[image]

There are some tricks though, like insetting the ngon (which will make it coplanar to its new adjacent faces), or using the *Weighted Normal* modifier:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, I removed the ngon to see what happens but I still have all the shading problems, maybe I didn't understand what you meant? 
https://imgur.com/a/qBVCrpI

Comment: I meant create quads instead of ngon, as you see on my picture, on the left there's a ngon, on the right I've made 2 quads instead

Comment: thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

[moonboots' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269746/what-am-i-doing-wrong-shading-and-modeling/269748#269748) is correct. Adding to that: For the vines, you can just use a spline all around the wood and add geometry to that spline so it will be like a cylinder all around.

Don't try to always add geometry to the same object if you don't know how to do that. Just add a new object and work with that one. Then you can see if it's useful to merge both in the same object or not.

Video game assets most of the time are not made of one primitive. It's a sum of various primitives.